# Joining multiple tables within an update statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join three tables within an update statement, but I have been unsuccessful so far. I know this query works for joining two tables:

```
update table 1
set x = X * Y
from table 1 as t1 join table 2 as t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

However, in my case, I need to join three tables so:

```
update table 1
set x = X * Y
from table 1 as t1 join table 2 as t2 join table3 as t3 
on t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t2.cloumn2 = t3.column1
```

Will not work. I also tried the following query:

```
update table 1
set x = X * Y
from table 1, table 2, table 3
where column1 = column2 and column2= column3
```

Does anyone know of a method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use `table, table, table` syntax; [here's why](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). As for your middle code sample, join syntax follows roughly the same rules for `SELECT` as it does for `UPDATE`. `JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON ...` is not valid, but `JOIN t2 ON ... JOIN t3 ON` is valid.

So here is my proposal, though it should be updated to fully qualify where `y` comes from:

```
UPDATE t1
  SET x = x * y  -- should either be t2.y or t3.y, not just y
  FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
  INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
  ON t2.column2 = t3.column1;
```